# Best Collation type and Promblems with user input

Tags: php, mysql

I have created several mysql  databases on my website (PHP)designed to allow users to advertise the books.

Many input excerpts and book descriptions which they cut and paste from .doc formatted documents.

Often there are weird characters in these files which output into the oddest posts with tm(trademark) all over the ' and " characters instead of the ' and the " what am I doing wrong. I've added a section of the print here to see if the same occurs.

Seventeen-year-old Rema lives in a brutal kingdom where travel between regions is forbidden, people are starving, and looking at someone the wrong way can mean death.

Nineteen-year-old Darmik is the king’s son and Commander of the King’s Army. He spends his days roving the island, doing his father’s bidding and trying to maintain control over the people.

Comment: On my site king's son would now read king @aktn s or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

set your db collation to **utf8_general_ci** for all fields

here is a code to change all fields collation for the entire db to **utf8_general_ci**

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
$db = 'db_name'; // your db name
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
$sql = "SHOW tables";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$rs) die('No Records !');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
   $tbl = $row[0];
   mysql_query("ALTER TABLE " . $tbl . " CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
}
mysql_close($con);
```